# Finding graph style in Plotly

Tags: python, graph, plotly, line

What is this type of graph(just a single line with one point on the line selected/highlighted) called and how can I graph it in plotly? I'm sure it's something absurdly simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out. See below:

[image: Example]

Went through various different plotly pages to try to find another example of this graph, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think plotly has this particular type of chart, but you can achieve this by adding two `go.Scatter` traces: the first trace with the argument `mode='markers+text'` to add the marker and the text inside, and the second trace with `mode='lines'` to add the line segment on the xaxis. Then to make the plot prettier, you can hide the yaxis and the ticks on the xaxis.

For example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0,96],
    y=[0,0],
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(
        color='blue',
        width=4,
    ),
    showlegend=False
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[96],
    y=[0],
    text="96",
    textposition="middle center",
    mode='markers+text',
    marker=dict(
        color='black',
        size=30,
        line=dict(
            color='white',
            width=1
        )
    ),
    textfont=dict(
        size=12,
        color="white"
    ),
    showlegend=False
))

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, showticklabels=False)
fig.update_layout(height=300, xaxis_range=[0,100], plot_bgcolor='black')
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped